# Getting Null Reference error when trying to set a picture in Telerik Gridview

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I'm trying to display pictures in a telerik gridview using the following bit of code:

```
  foreach (var item in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                item.Cells["column1"].CellElement.Text = "";
                item.Cells["column1"].CellElement.StretchVertically = true;
                item.Cells["column1"].CellElement.ImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
                item.Cells["column1"].CellElement.ImageAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                item.Cells["column1"].CellElement.Image = Image.FromFile("img/1.jpg");
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(item.Cells["Picture"].Value.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

But whenever i try to run the application , i get an error message complaining that the

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

What could be possibly wrong with it?!

Comment: Can you see what line it comes from? Maybe you can see that in `ex.StackTrace`. If, for example, it was in the first line of the `try` block, check all of the following: `item == null`, `item.Cells == null`, `item.Cells["column1"] == null`, `item.Cells["column1"].CellElement == null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Telerik Virtualization in the controls such as RadGridView CellElements and RowElements can be null.So in order to format certain cells e.g in a Telerik RadGridView control we need to use the "CellFormatting" event such as below:

```
 private void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.HeaderText == "Picture") 
                {
                    e.CellElement.Image = pictureBox1.Image;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The same approach is valid for formatting certain rows using RowFormatting event of course.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're dereferencing a null object (e.g. `null.SomeProperty`).

You should put a breakpoint on the line you're getting the error, and see which `null` object you're dereferencing.

Comment: I tried that. not either any row or cells are null . thats why im puzzled :-/

Comment: @Hossein see [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/gridview/update-cell-s-text-in-radgridview.aspx). I'm not familar with Telerik, but it looks like `CellElement` can be `null` because of grid virtualization. If that's the case, you'd be dereferencing a null object when you say `.CellElement.Text` since CellElement is null.

Comment: Ersonmez: Yes you are right.Due to Telerik virtualization , they were set to null! i had to use CellFormatting_Event to format certain cells .